# i want to display all data/ filter data from an excel file with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is what I get after running the code below which is supposed to filter the table:

[image].

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter as xs


need =("Algeria", "Angola", "Argentina", "Bangladesh", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", 
"Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Central African Rep.", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", "Congo, Republic", 
"Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cuba", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", 
"India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Marshall Island", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", 
"Namibia", "Nepal", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Rwanda", "Samoa", 
"Sao Tome and Principe", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Solomon Islands", "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "St Vincent and the Grenadines", "St.Kitts", "St.Lucia", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
"Uganda", "Uruguay", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Viet Nam", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe")

for root, dir, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        fi = file.split('.')
        if fi[-1] == 'xlsx':
            fil = file
            data = pd.read_excel(fil)
            filt = data[data['Recipient'] == need]
            filt.to_excel(f'{fi[0]}1.xlsx')
```

This is the original Excel file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace `filt = data[data['Recipient'] == need]` with
        `filt = data[data['Recipient'].isin(need)]`

Ths **isin()** function will fiter out the "data" to only rows whose **Reecipient** column value is in the set **need**